# Where does "find" fit on the abstract VBA Word object model?

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

The most useful piece of info I found to understand how VBA for Word works was the most abstract VBA object model (gotten from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw65a0we.aspx), which includes the most basic selecting objects, the ones you have to type first to refer to others. I have replicated it  below:

```
APPLICATION  
    DOCUMENT  
        BOOKMARKS  
            RANGE  
        RANGE   
            BOOKMARKS  
    SELECTION  
        BOOKMARKS  
            RANGE
        DOCUMENT
            RANGE
            BOOKMARKS
        RANGE
            BOOKMARKS
```

But how does "find", the most used selecting object (apart from those in the model), fit in it? I included the model so that it is easier for anyone to insert the object "find" wherever it fits. This way we could have a selection object map, the basic map for starting to understand VBA for Word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

14 days without answers (even though the question was voted as a good one during this time. Was it difficult?) has given me time to really understanding how this works to me. It's been really arduous, much more than it should, so maybe answering it avoids some new VBA programmers to spend as much time trying to grasp this as I did:

The trick lies in understanding two things:

1. that "properties" not only sets or returns the values of properties of an object, but also create an object with the very same name of the property (no value needed).
2. that the Word object model map in VBE is defined by the object-properties(&methods) relations not by the parent-son objects relations. The VBE F2 list of objects doesn't tell you anything about the object model, it just relates all objects (shown with the object symbol) to libraries. To figure out the model you need to find out the targeted property with the same name of the object (here `Find`), rather than the object itself, and see what objects contain it.

In this case VBE lists `Find` two times under the "Member" column, once for each object they are members of. The `Find` object can be created from  `Range` and `Selection`, so the previous hierarchy should be complemented this way:

```
APPLICATION  
    DOCUMENT  
        BOOKMARKS  
            RANGE
                FIND 
        RANGE   
            BOOKMARKS
            FIND  
    SELECTION  
        BOOKMARKS  
            RANGE
                FIND
        DOCUMENT
            RANGE
                FIND
            BOOKMARKS
        RANGE
            BOOKMARKS
            FIND
        FIND
```

Notice that the hierarchy would repeat the range-find relationship as you can access `Range` from different objects, but there's just one way to get a `Find` object from Selection.

Answer (score 0):

While your question and answer dives into the more abstract nature of `Find()` in Word, Stack Overflow typically dives more into the programming side of questions.  To that end it is important to note that the following method will allow you to search within each Story Range in Word:

Via http://word.mvps.org/faqs/customization/ReplaceAnywhere.htm

```
Public Sub FindReplaceAnywhere()
  Dim rngStory As Word.Range
  Dim pFindTxt As String
  Dim pReplaceTxt As String
  Dim lngJunk As Long
  Dim oShp As Shape
  pFindTxt = InputBox("Enter the text that you want to find." _
    , "FIND" )
  If pFindTxt = "" Then
    MsgBox "Cancelled by User"
    Exit Sub
  End If
  TryAgain:
  pReplaceTxt = InputBox( "Enter the replacement." , "REPLACE" )
  If pReplaceTxt = "" Then
    If MsgBox( "Do you just want to delete the found text?", _
     vbYesNoCancel) = vbNo Then
      GoTo TryAgain
    ElseIf vbCancel Then
      MsgBox "Cancelled by User."
      Exit Sub
    End If
  End If
  'Fix the skipped blank Header/Footer problem
  lngJunk = ActiveDocument.Sections( 1 ).Headers( 1 ).Range.StoryType
  'Iterate through all story types in the current document
  For Each rngStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    'Iterate through all linked stories
    Do
      SearchAndReplaceInStory rngStory, pFindTxt, pReplaceTxt
      On Error Resume Next
      Select Case rngStory.StoryType
      Case 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 , 11
        If rngStory.ShapeRange.Count > 0 Then
          For Each oShp In rngStory.ShapeRange
            If oShp.TextFrame.HasText Then
              SearchAndReplaceInStory oShp.TextFrame.TextRange, _
                  pFindTxt, pReplaceTxt
            End If
          Next
        End If
      Case Else
        'Do Nothing
      End Select
      On Error GoTo 0
      'Get next linked story (if any)
      Set rngStory = rngStory.NextStoryRange
    Loop Until rngStory Is Nothing
  Next

End Sub

Public Sub SearchAndReplaceInStory(ByVal rngStory As Word.Range, _
    ByVal strSearch As String , ByVal strReplace As String )

  With rngStory.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = strSearch
    .Replacement.Text = strReplace
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I was actually interested in the abstract part, in understanding it  conceptually. I initially posted it in the "Programmers" forum, which seems to be more conceptual, but they thought the question was better suited for StackExchange and moved it here... I'm not sure where does fit better, but knowing the object model seems to be very basic for programming at least in VBA, doesn't it? Your answers makes me think others could think the same as you though, so that gives me some perspective... thanks!